# display STDOUTs before STDERR?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I'm new to bash and I can not for the life of me figure out how to run a certain command, suppose `./fff` and print regular stdouts before stderr (I'm confused about the meaning myself)

for example

```
$ printf "I am a\ndrill\n" > fff; 
$ cat fff nofile fff nofile fff

I am a
drill
cat: nofile: No such file or directory
I am a
drill
cat: nofile: No such file or directory
I am a
drill
```

needs to print like:

```
I am a
drill
I am a
drill
I am a
drill
cat: nofile: No such file or directory
cat: nofile: No such file or directory
```

I understand that I need to redirect my output first to a file and then append the error to the same file however this is the output I get for

```
$ cat ./foo nofile ./foo nofile ./foo <<< $(touch fin) > see 2>> see 

I am a
drill
I am a
drill
I am a
drill
ectory
cat: nofile: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did `cat` really replace "a" by "some"?

Comment: oh dang I might have messed up the string. I'll edit it right away @DmitryGrigoryev

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll need to *hold* the stderr output somewhere anyway to be able to display it at the end.

A *file* comes to mind:

```
fff 2> file; cat file >&2
```

Or *memory* (here using `sponge` from `moreutils`):

```
{ fff 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | sponge >&2 3>&-; } 3>&1
```

- `{...} 3>&1`: within `{...}` file descriptor (fd) 3 points to the same resource as the *original* stdout (so we can use it to restore stdout for `fff`).
- `fff <redirs> | sponge <redirs>`, `fff` and `sponge` started concurrently (with `<redirs>` applied independently) with `fff`'s stdout going to a pipe, and `sponge`'s stdin being the other end of the pipe.
- `2>&1`: fd 2 of `fff` (stderr) points to the same thing as on 1: the pipe at this point, so `fff`'s error go to `sponge` via that pipe.
- `>&3`: now stdout points to the original stdout (redirect back to what it was)
- `3>&-`: we close fd 3 which `fff` doesn't need
- `sponge` accumulates its input and only displays it (on its stdout which has been redirected with `>&2` to the same resource as stderr) after it has detected eof on its stdin (assumed to be when `fff` terminates and has already written all its output on its stdout).

If `sponge` is not installed, you can replace it with `perl -0777 -pe ''`. With `-pe ''`, `perl` reads one record at a time from its input and writes it on stdout. `-0777` is the slurp mode where the (only one in that case) record is the whole input.

Comment: I still haven't advanced too much into unix as of yet (taking a course right now), but the first line about "holding the stderr somewhere" gave me the idea to do this (according to what I needed to do anyway)

`cat ./foo nofile ./foo nofile ./foo > fout.txt 2>> ferr.txt; cat fout.txt ferr.txt`

Comment: @MeOw: That’s fine, but, as the third line of Stéphane’s answer shows, you don’t need to save the stdout; just do `cat foo nofile foo nofile foo 2> ferr.txt; cat ferr.txt`.  (And you probably don t want to use `>>`.)  Also, Stéphane makes the excellent point that you should probably do `cat ferr.txt >&2` to write the stderr information *to* the stderr.

Comment: @G-Man you're right, `>>` was going to append everything, Noticed it quite later. I still, unfortunately, don't have the capability as of yet to understand what @Stéphane fully said, (I tried) but I will refer to it again once I do.

Also, `cat foo nofile foo nofile foo 2> ferr.txt; cat ferr.txt` prints out the stderr only once and not twice according to how many times I had invoked a non-existent file nofile (unless I'm being dumb and doing sth really wrong)?

Comment: Well, either there’s something wrong with your system, or you’re doing something wrong.  I just did that command (replacing `foo` with the name of a short file that I already had lying around) and I got `cat: nofile: No such file or directory` *twice* in my `ferr.txt` file.  Are you doing it all as one command, or as five separate ones?  What do you get if you do `cat nofile nofile 2> ferr.txt` (leaving out the good file)?

Comment: @G-Man I was doing it all `cat foo nofile foo nofile foo`. Absolutely no changes. I'll check the `cat nofile nofile` later sometime. It's probably the cloud9 that's messing up.. I'll try again and update.

Comment: @G-Man okay so I do get 2 errors `cat: nofile: No such file or directory` in my `ferr.txt`, however, when I cat it at last, only **one** of them show up in the console/terminal. Two errors in `ferr.txt` for `cat nofile nofile 2> ferr.txt` as well.

Comment: @MeOw: I don’t understand.  Are you saying that `cat ferr.txt` shows the error message only once, but if you look at `ferr.txt` *some other way (?)* you can see that it’s in there twice?