# Incorrect order of commands in "Command Substitution" (Bash/Dash)

Tags: bash, command-substitution, dash

Why is it that when you run the substitution commands, the order of execution is broken, as in the example below. First the `chmod` command was executed, then `echo 1` and `echo 2`?

```bash
echo $(echo 1; echo 2; chmod 444 nonexistent_file)
```

Result:

```
chmod: Cannot access 'nonexistent_file': No such file or directory
1 2
```

Comment: See [display STDOUTs before STDERR?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417124/display-stdouts-before-stderr)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order of execution isn’t broken, the output order isn’t what you expect.

`echo 1` and `echo 2` execute, writing their output to their standard output, which the shell accumulates for the command substitution. Then `chmod` executes, and outputs its error message to standard error, which goes straight to the terminal and thus appears first. Finally, the outer `echo` runs with the result of the command substitution, “1 2”.

Comment: About that, [Shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) warns [Useless echo? Instead of 'echo $(cmd)' just use cmd](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2005).